# Importing Gensim/Word2Vec not stable in Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, azure-databricks, gensim, word2vec

I am simply to import  import Word2Vec from gensim.models, but from few days I keep getting the following error :

```html
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

I tried updating my Numpy package to 1.24.1 (the latest) and Gensim package 4.3.0, but I still getting the same issue.

For details, I work with Python version 3.8.10 in Databricks.

Any idea please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 80 from PyObject

happens as a result of a modification made to the API of NumPy in version. Upgrading your `numpy` module version will fix the issue. few days ago, only ne `numpy` version 1.25.0 is released.

Try Uninstalling and reinstalling `numpy` in notebook or upgrade the version.

```bash
#uninstall install versions
%sh
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy

#upgrade version
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Also try with different `gensim` version.

I am successfully able to install:

[image]

Comment: after doing that I get this error (
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '_no_nep50_warning')

Comment: @Parik this is a new error : AttributeError: type object 'gensim.corpora._mmreader.MmReader' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Comment: I see that @pratik-lad is showing success with Python 3.9, while ~man-fan has mentioned using Python 3.8.10. Once you start getting such compatibility warnings, it's often best to *start with a fresh environment*, to ensure *nothing* based on mismatched interpreters/libraries persists. So ~man-fan, if you need to be using an older Python, create a plain fresh environment of that interpreter that works, then progressively install only & exactly the libraries you *now* need. Building up from scratch is the least likely to acquire mutually-incompatible droppings from prior tries (working or not).

Comment: If after building-back-up-from-scratch, you're getting new errors, those are likely separate isses that could deserve their own full question, which clearly describes the steps-to-reach & full-error-messages now being seen. A few short comments on an old question, describing multiple new error-excerpts (without full messages), that probably were *not* both the single outcome of one process, are very hard to interpret. (eg: What exactly was tried to reach these errors, at what step did they happen, was any other info shown?)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @gojomo and @pratik-lad for your feedbacks.

The best solution that I find to solve the issue of "binary incompatibility" is to edit my Databricks cluster and upgrade **Databricks runtime version** from 10.1 to 12.0.

I am now able to install **gensim**, with those version:

```html
Python 3.9.5
NumPy 1.21.5
SciPy 1.7.3
```